# How to measure Solidity variables size?

Tags: solidity, bytes

After reading different smart contracts from Uniswap teams and others, I understand that they stricly optimize the data to be stored on-chain, but how can they know what is the minimum size needed for each variable ?
For instance, I read that to store an NFT token on a Matic childchain, an if statement first checks the length of an input variable "tokenId" to be inferior to 32 bytes. How do they know precisely that it would need 32 bytes, and not 20 ?
The general question is how can I know/measure the number of bytes used for each specific variable I deal with in a smart contract ?

Comment: It depends on the contract you are writing. For example ERC20 and ERC721 have specifications where some values are defined precisely. If you are defining the contract then you decide according to the problem and data you have available. For example a timestamp you can use 256bits but it is a waste of space, 64 bits is enough for millions of years. For amounts 64bits can handle around quintillions, but perhaps it is too close and 96 bits will be good enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand the necessity of optimization to save gas cost, but based on your last anwer, I still do not know where to get the information that, using your example, 64 bits is enough for a timestamp, not 96 or 256. Sorry, I am a real beginner and I struggle to optimize my code as I don't have the information of the size requirements for each variables and I dont know where to find it except randomly on some forums from people presenting their code snippets for review.

Comment: I know each case is very specific but I am not aware of any tool or documentation saying that "you need in average 16 bytes for a timestamp, 96 bits for that time of variable declaration etc." Plus, I wonder if Remix, Truffle or any other web3 framework could give me the amount of bytes/bits used for each  specific variable I declare while coding or unit testing my code. To avoid setting some tresholds based on my or others people experience, which seems to be really not precise.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no rule that will always work, at least I'm not aware of such rule existence. It depends on the problem, on your experiences, the technical limitations. For solidity start with uint256 or bytes32 that are basic types, then refine when you have more knowledge about your problem. Usually uintXXX uses exactly XXX bits, uint128 uses 128 bits (16 bytes), and bytes20 uses 20 bytes (160 bits). Solidity has several rules and you'll learn them along the road, don't rush to known everything. It is a language that takes time.